# Add an hint field in the admin page of a plugin

Tags: wordpress

I made a plugin and now I'm making an admin page for it. I know how to properly add a field in an admin page but do you know how I can add an "hint field"?

Example : ["This address is used for admin purposes, like new user notification"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AnXCM.jpg).

Thanks

Comment: The http://stackoverflow.com/ may be not the best place to ask this question. You should look at http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: use https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_enqueue_scripts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how much code you've written so, short story, simply put the text in a `p` tag with `class="description"` to get the formatting you're looking for. But it seems like you might still be constructing the code for you options page and so I'm including the following code from the Stripe Checkout plugin which shows how they did it.

```
/**
 *  Main function to register all of the plugin settings
 *
 * @since 1.0.0
 */
function sc_register_settings() {

    global $sc_options;

    $sc_options = array();

    $sc_settings = array(

        /* Default Settings */

        'default' => array(
            'note' => array(
                'id'   => 'settings_note',
                'name' => '',
                'desc' => sprintf( '<a href="%s" target="_blank">%s</a>', sc_ga_campaign_url( SC_WEBSITE_BASE_URL . 'docs/shortcodes/stripe-checkout/', 'stripe_checkout', 'settings', 'docs' ), __( 'See shortcode options and examples', 'sc' ) ) . ' ' .
                          __( 'for', 'sc' ) . ' ' . Stripe_Checkout::get_plugin_title() . '<br/>' .
                          '<p class="description">' . __( 'Shortcode attributes take precedence and will always override site-wide default settings.', 'sc' ) . '</p>',
                'type' => 'section'
            ),
            'name' => array(
                'id'   => 'name',
                'name' => __( 'Site Name', 'sc' ),
                'desc' => __( 'The name of your store or website. Defaults to Site Name.' , 'sc' ),
                'type' => 'text',
                'size' => 'regular-text'
            ),
            'currency' => array(
                'id'   => 'currency',
                'name' => __( 'Currency Code', 'sc' ),
                'desc' => __( 'Specify a currency using it\'s ', 'sc' ) .
                            sprintf( '<a href="%s" target="_blank">%s</a>', 'https://support.stripe.com/questions/which-currencies-does-stripe-support', __( '3-letter ISO Code', 'sc' ) ) . '. ' .
                            __( 'Defaults to USD.', 'sc' ),
                'type' => 'text',
                'size' => 'regular-text'
            ),
            'image_url' => array(
                'id'   => 'image_url',
                'name' => __( 'Image URL', 'sc' ),
                'desc' => __( 'A URL pointing to a square image of your brand or product. The recommended minimum size is 128x128px.' , 'sc' ),
                'type' => 'text',
                'size' => 'regular-text'
            ),
            'checkout_button_label' => array(
                'id'   => 'checkout_button_label',
                'name' => __( 'Checkout Button Label', 'sc' ),
                'desc' => __( 'The label of the payment button in the checkout form. You can use {{amount}} to display the amount.' , 'sc' ),
                'type' => 'text',
                'size' => 'regular-text'
            ),
            'payment_button_label' => array(
                'id'   => 'payment_button_label',
                'name' => __( 'Payment Button Label', 'sc' ),
                'desc' => __( 'Text to display on the default blue button that users click to initiate a checkout process.' , 'sc' ),
                'type' => 'text',
                'size' => 'regular-text'
            ),
            'success_redirect_url' => array(
                'id'   => 'success_redirect_url',
                'name' => __( 'Success Redirect URL', 'sc' ),
                'desc' => __( 'The URL that the user should be redirected to after a successful payment.' , 'sc' ),
                'type' => 'text',
                'size' => 'regular-text'
            ),
            'disable_success_message' => array(
                'id'   => 'disable_success_message',
                'name' => __( 'Disable Success Message', 'sc' ),
                'desc' => __( 'Disable default success message.', 'sc' ) . '<br/>' .
                          '<p class="description">' . __( 'Useful if you are redirecting to your own success page.', 'sc' ) . '</p>',
                'type' => 'checkbox'
            ),
            'failure_redirect_url' => array(
                'id'   => 'failure_redirect_url',
                'name' => __( 'Failure Redirect URL', 'sc' ),
                'desc' => __( 'The URL that the user should be redirected to after a failed payment.' , 'sc' ),
                'type' => 'text',
                'size' => 'regular-text'
            ),
            'billing' => array(
                'id'   => 'billing',
                'name' => __( 'Enable Billing Address', 'sc' ),
                'desc' => __( 'Require the user to enter their billing address during checkout.', 'sc' ) . 
                        ( class_exists( 'Stripe_Checkout_Pro' ) ? '<br/><p class="description">' . __( 'See below if you also need to require a shipping address.', 'sc' ) . '</p>' : '' ),
                'type' => 'checkbox'
            ),
            'verify_zip' => array(
                'id'   => 'verify_zip',
                'name' => __( 'Verify Zip Code', 'sc' ),
                'desc' => __( 'Verifies the zip code of the card.', 'sc' ),
                'type' => 'checkbox'
            ),
            'enable_remember' => array(
                'id'   => 'enable_remember',
                'name' => __( 'Enable "Remember Me"', 'sc' ),
                'desc' => __( 'Adds a "Remember Me" option to the checkout form to allow the user to store their credit card for future use with other sites using Stripe. ', 'sc' ) .
                          sprintf( '<a href="%s" target="_blank">%s</a>', 'https://stripe.com/checkout/info', __( 'See how it works', 'sc' ) ),
                'type' => 'checkbox'
            ),
            'use_bitcoin' => array(
                'id'   => 'use_bitcoin',
                'name' => __( 'Enable Bitcoin', 'sc' ),
                'desc' => sprintf( __( 'Enable accepting <a href="%s" target="_blank">Bitcoin</a> as a payment option.', 'sc' ), 'https://stripe.com/docs/guides/bitcoin' ),
                'type' => 'checkbox'
            ),
            'disable_css' => array(
                'id'   => 'disable_css',
                'name' => __( 'Disable Plugin CSS', 'sc' ),
                'desc' => __( 'If this option is checked, this plugin\'s CSS file will not be referenced.', 'sc' ),
                'type' => 'checkbox'
            ),
            'always_enqueue' => array(
                'id'   => 'always_enqueue',
                'name' => __( 'Always Enqueue Scripts & Styles', 'sc' ),
                'desc' => __( 'Enqueue this plugin\'s scripts and styles on every post and page.', 'sc' ) . '<br/>' .
                          '<p class="description">' . __( 'Useful if using shortcodes in widgets or other non-standard locations.', 'sc' ) . '</p>',
                'type' => 'checkbox'
            ),
            'uninstall_save_settings' => array(
                'id'   => 'uninstall_save_settings',
                'name' => __( 'Save Settings', 'sc' ),
                'desc' => __( 'Save your settings when uninstalling this plugin.', 'sc' ) . '<br/>' .
                          '<p class="description">' . __( 'Useful when upgrading or re-installing.', 'sc' ) . '</p>',
                'type' => 'checkbox'
            )
        ),

        /* Keys settings */

        'keys' => array(
            'enable_live_key' => array(
                'id'   => 'enable_live_key',
                'name' => __( 'Test or Live Mode', 'sc' ),
                'desc' => '<p class="description">' . __( 'Toggle between using your Test or Live API keys.', 'sc' ) . '</p>',
                'type' => 'toggle_control'
            ),
            'note' => array(
                'id'   => 'api_key_note',
                'name' => '',
                'desc' => sprintf( '<a href="%s" target="_blank">%s</a>', 'https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/apikeys', __( 'Find your Stripe API keys here', 'sc' ) ),
                'type' => 'section'
            ),
            'test_secret_key' => array(
                'id'   => 'test_secret_key',
                'name' => __( 'Test Secret Key', 'sc' ),
                'desc' => '',
                'type' => 'text',
                'size' => 'regular-text'
            ),
            'test_publish_key' => array(
                'id'   => 'test_publish_key',
                'name' => __( 'Test Publishable Key', 'sc' ),
                'desc' => '',
                'type' => 'text',
                'size' => 'regular-text'
            ),
            'live_secret_key' => array(
                'id'   => 'live_secret_key',
                'name' => __( 'Live Secret Key', 'sc' ),
                'desc' => '',
                'type' => 'text',
                'size' => 'regular-text'
            ),
            'live_publish_key' => array(
                'id'   => 'live_publish_key',
                'name' => __( 'Live Publishable Key', 'sc' ),
                'desc' => '',
                'type' => 'text',
                'size' => 'regular-text'
            )
        )
    );

    $sc_settings = apply_filters( 'sc_settings', $sc_settings );

    $sc_settings_title = '';

    foreach( $sc_settings as $setting => $option ) {

        if( false == get_option( 'sc_settings_' . $setting ) ) {
            add_option( 'sc_settings_' . $setting );
        }

        add_settings_section(
            'sc_settings_' . $setting,
            apply_filters( 'sc_settings_' . $setting . '_title', $sc_settings_title ),
            '__return_false',
            'sc_settings_' . $setting
        );

        foreach ( $sc_settings[$setting] as $option ) {
            add_settings_field(
                'sc_settings_' . $setting . '[' . $option['id'] . ']',
                $option['name'],
                function_exists( 'sc_' . $option['type'] . '_callback' ) ? 'sc_' . $option['type'] . '_callback' : 'sc_missing_callback',
                'sc_settings_' . $setting,
                'sc_settings_' . $setting,
                sc_get_settings_field_args( $option, $setting )
            );
        }

        register_setting( 'sc_settings_' . $setting, 'sc_settings_' . $setting, 'sc_settings_sanitize' );

        $sc_options = array_merge( $sc_options, is_array( get_option( 'sc_settings_' . $setting ) ) ? get_option( 'sc_settings_' . $setting ) : array() );
    }

    update_option( 'sc_settings_master', $sc_options );

}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'sc_register_settings' );
```

You can see there that the text "The name of your store or website. Defaults to Site Name" is nested into the multidimensional array and also shows up on screen (I highlighted it): 
[image]

Comment: Thanks! I don't know why I was thinking about a harder solution than <p class="description">